# Load-balancing problem while implementing async HTTP with REST

Tags: rest, asynchronous, load-balancing, polling

I've read about asynchronous HTTP and REST and how can you return a resource after POST-ing to initiate a long running task and then polling that resource to get the task's status.
I wonder what happens if I have two machines that are load-balanced and one will receive the initial POST and the other a subsequent GET. The second will not be aware of what the first one started, unless I use a common storage to keep the task's state.
How can I prevent that if I want to keep the state only on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did the POST to initiate the long running task, you really should return a URI in the location header to point to the running task.  e.g.

```
POST /LongTasks
=>
201 Created
Location: /RunningTask/233


GET /RunningTask/233
=> 
Content-Type: text/plain

InProgress
```

At that point, you have a URL to the resource that represents the running task.  At that point the load balancing issue is the same as any other.  You cannot create state on the server that is accessible by the client that does not have a URI.

However, as long as those two loadbalancing servers are directly accessible you could do

```
POST http://example.org/LongTasks
=>
201 Created
Location: http://serverA.example.org/RunningTask/233


GET http://serverA.example.org/RunningTask/233
=> 
Content-Type: text/plain

InProgress
```

Comment: so the trick is to make the load balanced servers accessible individually if needed!

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is generally called client affinity. Basically, you cookie the client so that the load balancer knows which farmed application server to send a request to. Since the get and post will propagate the cookie, the queries for one user will always go to the same server. You can learn more about some of the config (using Apache as the reverse proxy to Tomcat) here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+mod_proxy

That said, using a shared storage is often lighter if you don't have a significant farm of backend processors. For example, with a few machines, using memcached as a lightweight storage for the status info is not a bad idea, and one that I have used successfully for both session data and status data.

Note also that using a reverse proxy solves the SSL issue (where you can't see the cookie with a hardware load balancer because of the encryption). The RP encodes/decodes and proxies to a backend server. Apache's mod_proxy is a common choice, though nginx is up and coming. You can also alternatively use IP-based affinity. However, I learned that was a bad idea the hard way once, when I realized that the entirety of a very large urban school system reads as one IP because of their filtering system :)

Comment: Yeah but the OP said REST.  You really shouldn't be identifying a resource via a cookie.  That's what the URI is for.

Comment: so I can identify the machine via URL or something like a sticky session, but that wouldn't be REST...

Comment: Well, I do love REST, but I have been finding recently that people take it a bit too much to heart. However, to split that hair, the situation itself is in contradiction with REST, because REST requires that no client context is stored on the server between requests. Since the process is left running **for** a client, we're already stateful. However, it's also possible to think of the session ID in the cookie as part of the information being passed back and forth explicitly. Alternatively, the server could return a check URL which encodes the session ID, too. That, or go IP-based...

Comment: @DavidF: Why not? REST APIs do allow the creation of a session token that then is used as a passed resource. A special URL parameter would simply be a session token of sorts. However, this question would still violate the cacheable and layered system constraints as mentioned in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).

Comment: Yes kind of violates this... "A client cannot ordinarily tell whether it is connected directly to the end server, or to an intermediary along the way."